# How to read borderless table using tabula 1.0.3 in java

Tags: pdf, text-extraction, tabula

I'm trying read data from text based pdf using Tabula. In certain pdf's the table does not have bottom border visible. Is there a way to read such pdf's?

```
            PDDocument pd = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));
            int totalPages = pd.getNumberOfPages();
            System.out.println("Total Pages in Document: "+totalPages);
            
            ObjectExtractor oe = new ObjectExtractor(pd);
            
            SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm sea = new SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm();
            
            Page page = oe.extract(1);
                // extract text from the table after detecting
                List<Table> table = sea.extract(page);
                
                System.out.println("table*** "+table.size());
                
                for(Table tables: table) {
                    List<List<RectangularTextContainer>> rows = tables.getRows();
                        for(int i=1; i<rows.size(); i++) {
                            
                            List<RectangularTextContainer> cells = rows.get(i);
                            for(int j=0; j<cells.size(); j++) {
                                System.out.print(cells.get(j).getText()+"|");
                }
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm` expects that a table is completely delimited by visible borders.

Perhaps you can use a combination of `SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm` and `BasicExtractionAlgorithm`. Some hints:

- Use `Page.getArea(...)` to get a region of a `Page`.
- Use `BasicExtractionAlgorithm` in the area *below* the detected table.
- Combine the extracted data.